# How to terminate a process in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, process, kill-process

if a process is not going to finish means if it getting **stucked**...
how can i **realize it and terminate it.**

i am working on a software which **processes millions of files** and each files takes few seconds to get process, but some files get stucked during processing, i want to **

> skip those files.

**
how can i do this??

details:

the files are first PARSED ------> then it is converted to .adv files ---------> later into triples .tpl

some files are getting stucked while generating .adv files.

Comment: You might want to try using timeouts.

Comment: i tried it using timer class but it consumes its own execution time, which eventually increases CPU overhead.

Comment: you can set a count value as a time  for particular thread, and if that time == some desired value , terminate that thread

Answer (score 1):

Decide how much time you are willing to spend generating one file before skipping it. You can set a timer with that time limit and check if it's still uploading the same file since the last time it went off. You shouldn't notice that much of a difference in CPU performance with just one timer that performs a simple check.

edit:

```
fileTimer = new Timer(maxDelay, checkFile);
fileTimer.start();
//set currentFile


ActionListener checkFile = new ActionListener() {
    String lastFile;
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (this.lastFile == currentFile)
            //terminate process
        else
            lastFile = currentFile
    }

}
```

I'm not quite sure how to terminate the process. I'm not super familiar with multi-threading. Any ideas on that @anshulkatta?

Comment: nice answer , elaborate a little , examples programatically